# Python. Функция не принимает массив в качестве аргумента

Tags: python, функции

При попытке запустить данный код, возникает ошибка **TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

```
    def find_Smallest(arr):
        smallest = arr[0]
        smallest_index = 0
        for i in range(1, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] < smallest:
                smallest = arr[i]
                smallest_index = i
            return smallest_index
    def selectionSort(arr):
        newArr = []
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            smallest = find_Smallest(arr)
            newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest))
        return newArr
    array = [5, 3, 6, 7, 10393, 0]
    print(selectionSort(array))
```

Как я понял, программа почему-то думает, что в функцию я должен передать число, а не массив. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ваша функция `find_Smallest` будет возвращать `None`, если самым маленьким окажется самый первый элемент массива. Да и в принципе она работает неправильно, потому что `return` прерывает работу цикла раньше чем нужно

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за исправления, но ошибка касается только аргументов моих функций.

Comment: Нет, ошибка заключается именно в этом, исправьте её прямо сейчас и попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: Вы правы, заработало. Прошу прощения :)